# How can I copy MS SQL database data for a date range to be appended to DB on another computer?

Tags: sql, vb.net, backup

I have a User Interface program written with VB.Net that collects instrumentation data from some PLC's and stores it in a MS SQL database. I need to be able to copy records from the DB based on a range of dates and save them in a file on a thumb drive. Then the file will need to be imported to a DB on another computer for analysis. I know SSMS can do a backup and restore but I don't think it can be based on a date range.

Comment: This question is way too broad for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest route I can think of would be (if the two DB are the same layout, table names etc) to download data, using a `DataAdapter`, into a DataTable and write it to disk with `DataTable.WriteXml()` then at the other end, `DataTable.ReadXml()` to get it from file back into a DataTable and write it into the destination DB with a DataAdapter. You'll need even fewer lines of code if you use strongly typed datatables (create a dataset)